# Getting Unix timestamp from the past with java 8

Tags: java

since Java 8 I can use [instant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

To get the Unix timestamp:

```
long unixTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

But if I want to get a time from the past, lets say 2 weeks I use this:

```
int unixtime2weeksAgo = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 14) / 1000L)
```

With the docu I couldn't build a solution based on the new java 8 features is here someone who could provide a good solution by using instant or LocalDateTime?

Comment: please have a look at `LocalDateTime::minus` method.

Comment: `Instant.now().getEpochSecond() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 14`?

Comment: Did you check the javadocs or API? It's literally right there - `Instant.ofEpochSecond(long epochSecond)`

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! Use java 8 date support, or for previous versions of java there is `joda-time` ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Two weeks ago" is dependent on your time zone (there may have been some DST changes etc.). So using `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` may create issues because they don't include any time zone information.

Assuming you want to do it in UTC, you can use:

```
ZonedDateTime twoWeeksAgo = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusWeeks(2);
long unixTs = twoWeeksAgo.toEpochSecond();
```

You can specify a [different time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in place of `ZoneOffset.UTC` seen above. For example, `ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )`.

Answer (score 5):

see below:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class TimestampExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long currentUnixTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
        System.out.println(currentUnixTimestamp);

        // two weeks ago
        long pastTimestamp = Instant.now().minus(14, ChronoUnit.DAYS).getEpochSecond();
        System.out.println(pastTimestamp);


    }
}
```